# python: how to put split conditions for csv reader

Tags: python, exception, csv

for memory problem I want to read a  text file in a csv format with python csv reader. Does anyone know how can I put an exception for that? The exception of only save the line that can be spliced into two peaces and not more.

here is my current code and I want to only get specific values for 'reader':

```
files = glob(path)
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for n,line in enumerate(f):
            reader = csv.reader(f.splitlines(), delimiter='|')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what about adding your condition and use the 'continue' command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it this way:

```
DELIMITER = '|'
files = glob(path)
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # only want rows containing delimiter
        filtered = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: DELIMITER in x, f)
        reader = csv.reader(filtered, delimiter=DELIMITER)
        for row in reader:
            # process each row (list of strings)...
```